# Question about Doob's optional stopping theorem proof

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a martingale sequence $X_0, X_1,...$
and $\tau$ is a stopping time bounded by a constant $c$.
Then Dooob's theorem states $E(X_{\tau}) = E(X_0)$.

I'm not understanding one part of the proof and any clarification is appreciated.
First write
$$
X_{\tau} = X_0 + \sum_{i = 0}^{c-1} (X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}
$$
so that
$$
E(X_{\tau}) = E(X_0) + \sum_{i = 0}^{c-1} E((X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}).
$$
and we just have to show
$$
E((X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}) = 0
$$
The first step is then this is
$$
E((X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}) = E( E((X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}) | \mathcal{F}_i )
$$
because $\tau \geq i + 1$ is determined by $X_0,...., X_i$. If someone could explain this step it be very appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
E((X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}) = E( E((X_{i+1} - X_i)1_{\tau \geq i + 1}) | \mathcal{F}_i )
$ is just the tower property of conditional expectation. After this you note that $1_{\tau \geq i + 1}$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F_i$ so it can be taken out of the conditional expectation. Once you do this you will have $E(X_{i+1}-X_i)$ which is $0$.